# Replace consecutive numbers in list with their min

Tags: python, list, integer, minimum

I have a list of integers and some of them are consecutive. I would like to either replace the consecutive ones with their group's minimum or delete all of them except each group's minimum. Example:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11]

result = [1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,11]
```

or even deleting them like so:

```
result = [1,6,11]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second way,

```
print([x for x in my_list if x-1 not in my_list])
```

gives you the list of all numbers for which the previous is not in the original list

Comment: You missed "consecutive"

Comment: Note: It is O(n^2) time complexity. If a set is built in advance for existence detection, it will be O(n).

Comment: Phu Ngo, if you remove from a list all the numbers that have a predecessor in the same list, you keep the minimum of all consecutive streaks... or I haven't understood your comment

Comment: @EnricoAgrusti for input `[2,1]`, the question requires an output of `[2,1]`, your answer gives `[1]`

Comment: or maybe OP really meant set...

Comment: Ah, you are correct! I assumed the list was ordered, which it may not be! EDIT: No wait, the question says "for all the consecutive streaks return the minimum" so the expected output IS [1]

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
>>> from itertools import pairwise
>>> result = [lst[0]]
>>> for i, j in pairwise(lst):
...     if j - i != 1:
...         result.append(j)
...
>>> result
[1, 6, 11]
```

Note: [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) was introduced in Python 3.10. If you are using an earlier version, you can consider implementing `pairwise` yourself or simply using indexes.

Comment: If OP is using Python 3.10, this is pretty neat.